# Files on a shared drived reverting to older versions after being saved by users

Tags: windows-server-2008

We just added ~15 people to our network over the last few months. Considering that we were around 35 before, it's a big increase.

It's not all been good though, since we're beginning to experience issues every now and then. From time to time, users are reporting that files are "reverting" to old versions. Ie. someone opens a file last modified at february 1st, modifies it and then saves the file on february 5th. The next day, the file will appear as it did on february 1st, including the time-stamp and all.

We're running Server 2008 (non-R2) and a mix of XP / Win7-clients. People are connected to a single share on a single fileserver via a logon-script.

I'm suspecting that VSS might be the culprit here.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Sounds like someone restored a previous version.  Do you have object access auditing enabled for that server?  If you want to know what happened and when, that is what you need to enable.

Comment: Hi Greg - Apologies for the late response. I figured I would get an email telling me there was a response here.